# Why is clone only cloning item once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jquery and I'm 100% sure I'm making a logical error but I can't see it. Basically as a user types a item in a field I want to clone the fields so they can continue adding more info.  In the example I'm working on, I'm trying to create a list of siblings and their age.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[name='age']").on('keydown', function() {
    //is it the last input?
    if (this == $("input[name='age']:last", this.form)[0]) {
        //insert an empty clone of the current input
        //$(this).after($(this).clone(true).val(''));
        $('.family').clone().insertAfter(".family");
    }
```

Here's the html:

```
<form>
<div class="family">
    <input name="age" value=0>  <input name="sibling" value="name?">
    <hr />
</div>
</form>
```

If I use `$(this).after($(this).clone(true).val(''));` then it works but it only clones one field(the age one) so I tried to replace it with `$('.family').clone().insertAfter(".family");` to clone the div class but it clones the fields only once.  If I start typing my first siblings info then the second form will appear but if I start typing on the second form then nothing new appears after that.

Its just a guess but I think the if statement is not matching so the clone isn't being created(I'm new so this idea could be wrong).  If this is the case then I'm confused because I'm cloning the same names of the input fields so `input[name='age']:last` should match the last age field..not sure.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to have to make your `keydown` event handler take note of future elements as well (i.e. the new `<div>` elements you're cloning and inserting).

Change

```
$("input[name='age']").on('keydown', function() {
```

to

```
$('form').on('keydown', 'input[name="age"]', function () {
```

#### i.e. (with some corrections / optimizations as well)

```
$('form').on('keydown', 'input[name="age"]:last-child', function() {

    var _p = $(this).parent('.family');

    // insert an empty clone of the current input's containing div
    // ADDED : ... after the current input's containing div
    _p.clone().insertAfter(_p);
}
```

Comment: I suspect the `.insertAfter()` is wrong too, because it'll insert a copy after _every_ existing copy, not just the last one.

Comment: Yeah, realized that as well. I put up an edit for it with untested code.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$("form").on('keydown',"input[name='age']:last", function() {
    $('.family:last').clone().insertAfter(".family:last");
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bhamU/)**

The issue is that you're trying to bind to elements that don't yet exist. To do that using .on(), you just need to bind to an element that exists in the dom:

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event
>   handler, as described next.

Then, you want to make sure you're only checking and cloning the last div and it's input. Note that when you're cloning the input fields, you will need to either change the names so you don't end up with a bunch of them that use the same name, or with a language like PHP you can append `[]` after the name and PHP will parse that into an array.